# Python - inserting new line in Tkinter Label

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I am not able to insert new line in the output that is generated using `Label` in Tkinter. Below is the image of my GUI that explains my problem.

[image]

This is the code that I used for defining my label.

```
string1 = 'At pathID' + str(l.get('pathId'))+
          'In label' + str(keys) +':'+
          'profile in reference but not in copy' + 
           str(list(set(a_value)-set(b_value)))            

ttk.Label(t.sub_frame, text=string1).pack(side="left", fill="x", expand=1)
```

**What I want:**

I want a new line at the beginning of `At path ID0 in label.....`

So the output in label should look like below and not like shown in one line above in GUI image:

`At path ID0 In label1: profile in reference but not in copy[(18,0,0)]
At path ID0 In label2: profile in reference but not in copy[(18,0,8)]`

**What I tried:**

The above shown lines are generated in loop so I tried keeping new line character before start of the line, but it only shows the output from next line yet keeping it attached in one line.

```
string1 = '\n' + '\nAt pathID' + str(l.get('pathId'))+
              'In label' + str(keys) +':'+
              'profile in reference but not in copy' + 
               str(list(set(a_value)-set(b_value)))
```

The reason I assumed was that at every loop new line character will be encountered and I can get every line printed in newline. Can you guys suggest me something? I think I am missing a minor logic somewhere

Comment: Why are you using `/n`? A newline is `\n`. Try this in the interpreter: `print('hello\nworld')`

Comment: sorry for the wrong character. In the code I am using correct one. by mistake I used `/n` here. Let me edit question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why but due to something, the values in `pack` were causing some problems. I edited my code like shown below. Now its working fine.

`ttk.Label(t.sub_frame, text=string1).pack()`

Thank you guys for your attention.

Comment: Its recommended to use `pack()` in a separate line on a reference of the object: `label = ttk.Label(t.sub_frame, text=string1); label.pack()`.Maybe your parameters in `pack()` would work this way.

If you know the width you can also set `wraplength` of your label: `ttk.Label(parent, text="longtext..." wraplength=20)`, this will break your text automaticly after the given width is reached. 

Also you should use `format()` for formating your strings, see: [clickme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format)

Comment: This is whats your string would look like: `string1 = 'At pathID {0}  In label {1} : profile in reference but not in copy {2}'.format(l.get('pathId'), keys, list(set(a_value)-set(b_value))) `

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you VRage.

Comment: I definitely have to format my strings and in my case I cannot use `wraplength` because the length of string is not fixed.

Comment: Maybe in other cases this [text wrapping](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html) module comes in handy, so keep that in mind

Comment: Sure. I'll keep in mind.